# I can't change country/region of my Apple account!

Tags: iphone, ios-appstore

I can't change country/region of my Apple account. The steps I followed:

1. Tap on the App Store icon in your home screen
2. Tap on featured on the bottom left corner of screeen
3. Scroll all the way to the bottom where your Apple ID info is
4. Tap View Apple ID, you may have to enter your password
5. Once the page loads change your country/region

I do not seem to have the option to change country/region, it is there it is shown but I can't select and change it. It happens both on my iPhone and on my PC application of iTunes.

Is there any other way I can change it?

Comment: Which country does it show now?

Answer (score 2):

Go to https://appleid.apple.com/#!&page=signin

1. Login with your Apple ID
2. Enter your security answer if asked for
3. It will open a page with account settings
4. Click edit on first section where your address is shown
5. Modify your address and click Done

Vola... Your country is changed in Apple ID :) enjoy

Answer (score 0):

Your account needs to have no money on it to change the region.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change it on your iPhone , try changing account settings then back to set the country and region. You can also change it on iTunes.

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps.

1. Click on settings icon in home page
2. Go to itunes and app store
3. Click on the part at the top
4. Select view apple id
5. Try changing it there.

If it still does not work, creating a new apple ID is really easy and takes no time at all. I would even suggest that you actually have two accounts, as some country's app stores has other apps that cannot be found on others. The apps are either country specific or just not yet accepted in certain countries. Therefore, the more accounts, the more available apps

Answer (score -1):

Login to another iCloud acc and then log back in. It will set it to its default country unless the other account had the same country.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  We like answers to be more than just a single line.  Ideally, you want to explain why your answer is *right."  It also helps to provide links, citations, and/or screen shots.  Please review our help section [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on writing good answers to questions